# Duplicate zip entry error android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am  trying to build the apk but it is giving unknown error i tried many solutions but didnt hepled.
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.

> java.io.IOException: Can't write [\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\release\jars\3\1f\main.jar] (Can't read [\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\22.0.0\jars\libs\internal_impl-22.0.0.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [android/support/v4/view/ap.class == internal_impl-22.0.0.jar:android/support/v4/view/WindowInsetsCompat.class]))

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my_directory"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.0.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
compile 'net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
```

}

Comment: You are including `support-v4` twice, from sources that Gradle cannot reconcile. You might consider editing your question and posting your `app` module's `build.gradle` file, and perhaps we can see specifically where this is occurring.

Comment: If you have a support library jar file in the libs folder (such as when coming from Eclipse), then remove it

Comment: I only have one gcm jar in lib folder @cricket_007

Comment: added the gradle file @CommonsWare

Comment: If `gcm.jar` is the GCM part of Play Services, get rid of that. You are already pulling in GCM via `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'`.

Comment: okk will check@CommonsWare

Comment: If i remove this jar it is not able to recognize the Gcm classes @CommonsWare

Comment: Then you are using the wrong classes, presumably. The GCM API has changed over the years. 7.0.0 of the Play Services SDK is fairly old (current is 9.8.0, and GCM has been deprecated in favor of Firebase Cloud Messaging anyway).

Comment: As CommonsWare said, and also, you need `recyclerview-v7:22.2.0`... This version must match the `appcompat-v7` library